# Laravel 6 - Password confirmation

Tags: php, laravel, passwords, confirm

I'm following along with [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#password-confirmation)
which says that you can configure Laravel to get the user to re-enter their password on routes that you specify. However, if I follow the example I get an error:

```
 Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
```

```
Target class [password.confirm] does not exist.
```

Any ideas? I'm running Laravel 6.16.0. I'm also using the LdapRecords package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorted it. I've been upgrading Laravel 6.0 since initial release to get to 6.16.0. This feature was added in 6.2, however my Kernel.php was still like the original version. All I needed to do was add:

```
'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
```

to the routeMiddleware section of Kernel.php.